# AppDelegate.m needs to send data to a separate ViewController's WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, viewcontroller, appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

     if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"mycustomscheme"]) {

          NSString *urlString = @"http://google.com/";
          NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
          NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
          [tapView loadRequest:loadObj];

     }
}
```

"tapView" (a UIWebView) works fine inside "ViewController.m", but when I use it inside of "AppDelegate.m" it won' work. What do I need to do special to make this code run inside of my "AppDelegate.m" file. I would appreciate a step-by-step explanation as I am a web designer, not a programmer, hehe. :)

What my code is attempting to do is detect a "mycustomscheme://" being loaded in Safari and of course launching the app, and then load google.com into the UIWebView (to prove it's working). I somehow need to connect the tapView so it is manipulated by AppDelegate.m.

Comment: Is ViewController the root view controller of your window?

Comment: I don't think so. I honestly don't know. (Extra Info: I'm using a very simple setup with AppDelegate.m, ViewController.m, a storyboard, and of course a main.m file - but it's literally just a single WebView app, the webview is inside of ViewController.m)

Comment: Then, yes, ViewController is the window's rootViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@daemon use NSNotificaitonCenter

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
 {
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"mycustomscheme"]) 
    {
      NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"http://google.com/" forKey:@"urlToLoad"];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil userInfo:aDict];

     }
 }
```

add observer in your viewcontroller

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(LoadRequestFromAppDel:) name:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil];

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
 -(void)LoadRequestFromAppDel:(NSNotification*)aNotif
 {
    NSString *aStrUrl=[[aNotif userInfo] objectForKey:@"urlToLoad"];
    NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:aStrUrl];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [tapView loadRequest:loadObj];
 }
```

Comment: I ended up using this for the final integration. It carries the url over to the other view perfectly. Both solutions work, but I'm finding that this one is the best for my needs.

Comment: Don't forget to remove observer after finishing task

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil];

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to let ViewController do the loading of its own web view, so you should create a method in that controller to handle that operation (in ViewController.m):

```
-(void)loadWebViewFromAppDelegate {
     NSString *urlString = @"http://google.com/";
     NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [tapView loadRequest:loadObj]; // I'm assuming that tapView is a property or outlet in this controller
}
```

In the app delegate, get a reference to that controller, and call its method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

     if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"mycustomscheme"]) {
         ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
         [vc loadWebViewFromAppDelegate];
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried something like this before, but I'm obviously missing something... It says a warning and an error in my AppDelegate.m file... Incompatible pointer types initializing ViewController with an expression of type UIViewController... and under that is No visible @interface for ViewController declares the selector loadWebViewFromAppDelegate

Comment: @daemon, did you import ViewController.h in to the app delegate .m file?

Comment: #import "ViewController.h" is at the top, yes.

Comment: @daemon, You need to put -(void)loadWebViewFromAppDelegate; in the .h file of ViewController, so that the compiler knows that method exists.

Comment: @daemon, Also, I forgot a cast in the line where I define vc -- see my edit.

Comment: This Worked! Perfect. I was looking all over for info regarding this, and it was nowhere. Thank you rdelmar x1000, and everyone else who attempted as well - but this path definitely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new controller for loading the UIWebView

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

     if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"mycustomscheme"]) {

      // here
      WebViewController* webView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:NO];

     }
}
```